# Why is Dialogflow CX referencing gcloud's project (project-number)?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am working the Dialogflow CX Java SDK to execute a list agents command.  When, I try to list the agents, I get this exception.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Dialogflow API has not been used in project project-number before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/overview?project=project-number then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

Relevant code snippet:

```
AgentsSettings agentsSettings = AgentsSettings.newBuilder().build();

AgentsClient client = AgentsClient.create(agentsSettings)
LocationName parent = LocationName.of("my project id", "US-CENTRAL1");
AgentsClient.ListAgentsPagedResponse agents = client.listAgents(parent);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the enabling the Dialogflow API as suggested by the error message? You can do this by going to "APIs & Services" > Library > Search for "Dialogflow API" > Choose "Enable". Also just to confirm, is the referenced project by Dialogflow is your actual project?

Comment: My project has a completely different id.  The id in the error message is the GCP project for gcloud.  Clicking on the link results in security errors as it should.

Comment: A further mystery is I have a separate ES Java SDK program that works ok.

Comment: By any chance, were you using a different project credentials when the code was ran? Also can you confirm if your created agent is located in `us-central1`?

Comment: Same creds.  Agent is us-central1.  Not really sure what is going on.

Comment: It might be better to contact [GCP support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) if you have free trial credits or an existing support package for this to be looked into.

Answer (score 0):

This error may indicate that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and/or `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` environment variables were not properly set. Reviewing the [Dialogflow CX Setup](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/setup) documentation may help.