# How to receive BigQuery SELECT instruction result faster?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, google-bigquery

I use Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 (2.3.0) and this code to make queries:

```
GoogleCredential gc = GoogleCredential.FromFile(bq_json_path);
BigQueryClient bq_client = BigQueryClient.Create(bq_project_id, gc);
string query = "SELECT " + columns2select + " FROM " + project_dataset_table + ";";
BigQueryResults bqr = bq_client.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters: null);

IEnumerator<BigQueryRow> itr = bqr.GetEnumerator();

while(itr.MoveNext())
{
    //do something (even if I comment it and do nothing, it save only 2 seconds)
}
```

That way it process 100k rows for 26 seconds. That's ultimate slow.

I tried using `bqr.ReadPage(100000);`, but it also took ~26 seconds to retrieve the rows just by that call.

I doing the program to transfer data from BigQuery into ClickHouse for DataLens analysis purpose. And 100k rows insertion into cloud hosted ClickHouse (not on my local PC) takes just 1-2 seconds. That's weird imbalance. I think selecting rows should be way more faster.

P.S. 100k rows per 26 seconds is not a problem... The problem is that I need to transfer many tables with ~60 millions records and some tables can have even 1 billion of records.

Comment: There are lots of ways to improve query performance, for starters, you may start with this GCP documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview

Comment: @AnjelaB - How the simplest select query can be improved? How this documentation about improving query performance can help me to improve query result READING performance?

Comment: If the documentation was not helpful to you, you can contact GCP Support [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266748/why-is-dialogflow-cx-referencing-gclouds-project-project-number#:~:text=better%20to%20contact-,GCP%20support,-if%20you%20have) so they can do root cause analysis for this case since we won't be able to reproduce this scenario and we have limited access.